# How can i add image in "item element" in Rss?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rss

GetProductData return correct image url but in my ashx page it doesn't appear. Can anybody help me?

```
    List<ProductItem> p = ProductFactory.GetProductData();

    foreach (ProductItem c in p)
    {
        rss.WriteStartElement("item");
        rss.WriteElementString("title", c.Page_Title);
        rss.WriteElementString("link", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(BaseSiteUrl + c.Page_Url.Replace("~", "")));
        rss.WriteElementString("description", c.Page_Description);
        rss.WriteElementString("pubDate", DateTime.Now.ToString());

        //object pho_url = ProductFactory.GetProductImageUrl(c.ProductID);
       //How can i add image element here...

        rss.WriteElementString("guid", "guid field");
        rss.WriteEndElement();

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally it's done in it's own namespace, here's an example from techcrunch's feed.

```
<media:content url="http://www.mobilecrunch.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/01/iphone3gs11.jpg" medium="image">
   <media:title type="html">iphone3gs11</media:title>
</media:content>
```

Then you'll need to add the namespace as an attribute on <rss>

xmlns:media="search.yahoo.com/mrss/"

This is what I believe apps like pulse and flipboard try to use for there visual readers.

Comment: Do you have your namespace and element mixed up? `media:content` vs `content:media` - the xmlns declares 'content', but not 'media'

Comment: Sorry my fault, grabbed the wrong namespace from the <rss>
Should be the following
xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"

Answer (score 1):

RSS 2.0 includes the optional 'enclosure' element. You could use that. According to the [definition](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html) it

> describes a media object that is attached to the item

Answer (score 0):

Item element does not support Image.
[RSS 2.0 Specification](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html)